# Unable to boot Ubuntu - dual environment with Raid

Tags: installation, dual-boot, grub2, raid

My new desktop has the following configuration (1 SSD with windows 7 installed) and a 2TB pair of Raid 1 disks.

Windows is installed on the SSD (120Gb) which includes a boot partition.

I have split the 2TB "raid-1) disk into 3 partitions (large NTFS partition), and 2 smaller partitions for Ubuntu (swap & Ext4)

I installed Ubuntu (or I think I have) installed Ubuntu on the two partitions and everything seems to be there, but I do not get a the GRUB 2 boot manual, and the installation ubuntu does not seem to detect windows 7 presence and I do not get the prompt at the end of the installation to ask where I would like to store the boot.  Indeed, the only option I get for defining the boot option is on the raid disks, not on the SSD.

I have tried to resolve the problem using Boot-repair-disk and it hangs on the line "sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/mapper/****" apt-get purge -y -force-yes grub*-common shim-signed linux-signed*.

Comment: Is your system UEFI or BIOS? Normally with BIOS boot grub should install to root of the mapper as BIOS boots from that. But with UEFI I am not sure, but think it still has to boot from efi partition outside of RAID as UEFI only reads FAT32 partitions, not RAID. If UEFI, is secure boot on also? You mention signed kernel versions which are for secure boot.

Comment: It is a UEFI environment.

Answer (score 0):

See this bug report, there are several work arounds.  You may just need the grub.cfg stub in the efi partition to load the RAID drivers and find grub in the RAID.

grub doesn't boot with efi and md raid root

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1229738